# String comparison fails even when visually checked

Tags: c#, datetime

I added a function to my application recently that reads a date from a downloaded file and finds the difference in days between current date and the date from the file.  When done, it is displayed in a label in one of my forums.

There is an exception: if the string in the file equals "Lifetime", it should not process it as a date and follow alternate logic. But when I try to check if the string is "Lifetime", it does not return true, even if the string = "Lifetime".

**EDIT: I fixed the FormatException with help from Nisarg.  Now, my labels aren't changing to the values.  This is the problem.**

**EDIT2: I feel stupid.  I found out that I was initiating Main twice in one function, then using main1 to switch between forms and main to set the labels. 
 This is why the labels weren't working right.  Thanks Nisarg and all other contributors.**

Code example:

```
string subScript = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetTempPath() + txtUsername.Text + ".txt");
Main main = new Main();
double dSubLeft;
main.dateLabel.Text = subScript;

if (subScript == "Lifetime") // it bypasses this, apparently blank
{
    main.daysLeftLabel.Text = "Expires: Never";
}

if (subScript != "Lifetime") //Goes here and throws error saying subScript is not valid DateTime
{
    dSubLeft = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToDateTime(subScript)) - DateTime.Now).TotalDays)));
    string sSubLeft = Convert.ToString(dSubLeft);
    main.daysLeftLabel.Text = "Expires: " + sSubLeft + " Days";
}
```

Comment: Does this line **string subScript = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetTempPath() + txtUsername.Text + ".txt");** fill string data in the variable

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime()` needs a string that looks like a date (like 7/14/2017"). You are sending it the string "Lifetime" which can't be converted.

Comment: @Kevin yes, but I checked to make sure that it does not equal Lifetime.  Shouldn't that stop it?

Comment: @RahulKurup yes.

Comment: If so, try using **main.dateLabel.Text** instead of **subScript** and check if the same happens

Comment: @RahulKurup Same thing happens.

Comment: @elite, Almost *all* strings do not equal "Lifetime". So if `subScript` *is* anything but "Lifetime" the code assumes it is a date and then fails.

Comment: @Kevin I manage the file on my webserver, I am pretty sure `subScript == "Lifetime"`

Comment: @elite, If that were true wouldn't it print "Expires: Never"? The comments in the code suggests it is running the second if statement.

Comment: @Kevin The thing is, the string does equal "Lifetime", because I check it with a label.  I can't figure out why its bypassing the first statement.

Comment: @elite, the answer below will probably solve the issue. The file may *look* like it only has the string, but spaces, tabs, etc can't be seen but are actually in the `subScript`

Comment: @Kevin The post by Nisarg fixed my FormatException problem, but the string is still setting the label as blank.  This is making no sense.

Comment: Check the file with an editor that displays the hex values. You will probably find some extra newlines that are messing it up.

Comment: @Kevin The problem now is my labels are not changing.  I set daysLeftLabel.Text to "test", and after initiating the function, it stays at "test".

Comment: Is it an aspx page with name `main.aspx`? Then you don't need `Main main = new Main();`. Also don't access your labels via `main`, just set them using `dateLabel.Text = subScript;`, `daysLeftLabel.Text = "Expires: Never";` and `daysLeftLabel.Text = "Expires: " + sSubLeft + " Days";`

Answer (score 2):

While using files you often get trailing blank spaces or newline characters. Try trimming the string before comparing it to `Lifetime`:

```
subScript = subScript.Trim().Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

Another (less likely) problem could be with the comparison itself. In C# the comparison in case-sensitive. So if you're comparing `lifetime` with `Lifetime` they are considered unequal. You should rather use case-insensitive comparison:

```
if(string.Equals(subScript, "Lifetime", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

OR

```
if(subScript.ToLower() == "lifetime")
```

You could also check if the `subScript` you are getting from the file is a valid date or not using `DateTime.TryParse`.

```
string subScript = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetTempPath() + txtUsername.Text + ".txt");
Main main = new Main();
double dSubLeft;
main.dateLabel.Text = subScript;
DateTime subScriptDate;

if(!DateTime.TryParse(subScript, out subScriptDate))
{
    main.daysLeftLabel.Text = "Expires: Never";
}
else  //Goes here and throws error saying subScript is not valid DateTime
{
    dSubLeft = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString((subScriptDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays)));
    string sSubLeft = Convert.ToString(dSubLeft);
    main.daysLeftLabel.Text = "Expires: " + sSubLeft + " Days";
}
```

Comment: I set the text file to say Lifetime.  I did that because I knew it would be case-sensitive and it would screw me up later.  As far as extra characters go... I have tried that, and nothing changed.

Comment: Okay, maybe you could try a better condition. I would add a snippet for DateTime.TryParse instead of string comparison. See if that helps.

Comment: This fixed the FormatException, but the string still shows up as blank.

Comment: 1. Have you been able to debug the program to see exactly what you are getting in the `subScript` variable? You should also check that the file being read is the one you intend to. 2. If you are certain that the file can either have a valid date or "Lifetime" written in it, just test the code with a valid date in it. Does that work? .

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because main is the starting point of a program in C#, make another methodname if you don´t want it to reset things from where the program is supposed to start from

That is my guess only, make a breakpoint in the beginning of your code and check through what info you get from each row in the code

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, the actual content of the string is not actually the string "Lifetime".  Probably because of white-space on either side.  Try trimming.

Relevant edit:

```
if (subscript.Trim() == "Lifetime")
{
    main.daysLeftLabel.Text = "Expires: Never";
}
else // don't retest for the opposite condition
{
...
```

As you can see, this thing is awfully fragile, because the string could still be many things that aren't a valid `DateTime`.  Smells like homework, but there you go...

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
    if(string.Equals(subScript, "Lifetime", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
//statement

}
else
{
//statement

}
```